# Determine if neighbors exist?

Tags: ruby

I have a reference hash of all possible ranks that looks like this:

```
hash = {
  bronze: 0,
  silver: 1,
  gold: 2,
  platinum: 3,
  diamond: 4
}
```

I get a given rank, and an array of other existing ranks, and I need to determine if 'neighbors' exist for the given rank.  I'll try an example:

```
given_rank = 'gold'  
existing_ranks =  ['silver', 'platinum']
```

This should return `true` - silver is directly beneath gold and platinum is directly above - both neighbors are present.

```
given_rank = 'gold'  
existing_ranks =  ['silver', 'diamond']
```

This should return `false` - platinum is missing on the upper side

Here's what I have now:

```
user_rank = hash[given_rank]
higher = hash.invert[user_rank + 1]
lower = hash.invert[user_rank - 1]

if existing_ranks.include?(higher) && existing_ranks.include?(lower)
  # do something
else
  # do another thing
end
```

Is there a more effective/efficient/ruby way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the trivial mathematical relationship between consecutive indexes, you can write:

```
n1, n2 = hash.values_at(*existing_ranks)
are_neighbors = (n1 - n2).abs == 2 && hash[given_rank] == (n1 + n2) / 2
```

Comment: do you mean `(n2 - n1).abs == 2`?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of advice, : work with symbols instead of strings for your ranks.

```
hash = {
  bronze: 0,
  silver: 1,
  gold: 2,
  platinum: 3,
  diamond: 4
}
given_rank = :gold
existing_ranks =  [:silver, :platinum]

is_neighbor = existing_ranks.map{ |rank| (hash[rank] - hash[given_rank]).abs }.uniq == [1]
```

Now you shoulod have `is_neighbor == true` if both of your existing_ranks is a neighbor of your given rank

Answer (score 0):

```
def correct_ordering?(hash, existing_ranks, given_rank)
  hash.values_at(*existing_ranks).sort == [hash[given_rank]-1, hash[given_rank]+1]
end

existing_ranks = [:silver, :platinum]

correct_ordering?(hash, existing_ranks, :gold)    #=> true
correct_ordering?(hash, existing_ranks, :diamond) #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

When a key is not found in a hash, then the result is `nil`.Just delete the `nil` to get the valid neighbor(s)

```
hash = {
  bronze: 0,
  silver: 1,
  gold: 2,
  platinum: 3,
  diamond: 4
}

given_rank = 'gold'
existing_ranks =  ['silver', 'platinum']

ranks = hash.invert
r = hash[given_rank.to_sym]
# compact method deletes nil values:
p existing_ranks.map(&:to_sym) == [ranks[r-1], ranks[r+1]].compact # => true
```